# Button that opens the default mailbox

Tags: html, mailto

It is possible to open the user mailbox for composing a new message to a specific address, using the property `mailto:<mail>` on a `button`. However is it possible to simply open the mailbox without composing a new message? This would be useful when the user received a mail, for example when resetting their password.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick on Windows 10:

```
<a href="OUTLOOKMAIL:">Outlook</a>
```

There is a bunch more that you could possibly use that might be more appropriate for your task, listed under the Windows Settings > Apps > Default Apps > Choose default apps by protocol.

Not sure if these are universal over other Operating Systems though.
This also does rely on the user having made the protocol type association to an app first though.